# Phonegap media: "Reference error media not defined "

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, media

This question answered many times, but I still can't fix my problem. I'm trying to play a music when my scene starts, I'm using Media class, but I get the error ReferenceError: Media is not defined. I'm using browser yet (I want to deploy it to android and ios later).

I'm using Cordova 3.5, PhoneGap 3.6.
Here's what I did so far:

**1**

ran the command in the command line standing in my project directory: `cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-media.git`

**2**

modified the config xml:

```
   <feature name="Media">
        <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.media.AudioHandler" />
    </feature>
```

**3**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

My js code is:

```
var music = new Media("sounds/main_theme.ogg");
```

Comment: ever figure this out?

Comment: the solution is: never use PhoneGap, if you want a cross-platform solution, use Unity, that is the only one what works as intended

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using PhoneGap via [this tutorial](http://coenraets.org/blog/phonegap-tutorial/), rather use command line cordova via [this tutorial](http://ccoenraets.github.io/cordova-tutorial/create-cordova-project.html).